# Disable Block Editor for specific ID's of a CPT

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to disable the Gutenberg editor for some posts of a CPT and have this little function which is working.

```
function prefix_disable_gutenberg($current_status, $post_type)
{
    // Use your post type key instead of 'product'
    if ($post_type === 'my_cpt' && get_the_ID() == 116 || get_the_ID() == 114 || get_the_ID() == 119 || get_the_ID() == 1743 ) return false;
    return $current_status;
}

add_filter('use_block_editor_for_post_type', 'prefix_disable_gutenberg', 10, 2);
```

Is there a more elegant way to check the ID's? I tried around with the little bit I know about arrays but I couldn't get it running. Appreciate any help!

UPDATE/SOLUTION

Thanks to hakre's hint I was able to find the solution. The missing part was the `global $post;` to be able to use the ID as $needle in the in_array function.

```
function prefix_disable_gutenberg($current_status, $post_type) {
    global $post;
    $ids = array(114, 116, 119, 1743, 23, 112);
                
    if ($post_type === 'my_cpt' && in_array($post->ID, $ids)) return false;
    return $current_status;
}

add_filter('use_block_editor_for_post_type', 'prefix_disable_gutenberg', 10, 2);
```

Comment: https://php.net/in_array

Comment: I tried around with that already. I either get an error or the function does nothing... I'm not very used to php but I guess the problem is the $needle ...


```function prefix_disable_gutenberg($current_status, $post_type) {
 
 $ids = array(114, 116, 119, 1743, 23, 112);
    
 if ($post_type === 'my_cpt' && in_array((int)$post->ID, $ids)) return false;
    return $current_status;
}

add_filter('use_block_editor_for_post_type', 'prefix_disable_gutenberg', 10, 2); ```

Comment: Please edit that into your question, appending it. The comment is hard to read especially for the code block that is inlined, ping me then.

Comment: @hakre I updated my post! Found the solution thanks to your help, appreciate it!